# Which virtualization applicaton is compatible with regular antiviruses?

Tags: antivirus, virtualization

I know that such soft as BitDefenter or Kaspersky will not work under VirtualBox. I know also that there are some specific kinds of antiviruses designed specifically for work under virtual enviroments, but I'm interested in regular antiviruses. What alternative to VirtualBox would you offer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally avoid an open-source software like VirtualBox because exactlly that "liberty" of code is what makes it a bad choice for specific requisites like this.

I recommend you privative VMWare products, you can choose between VMWare Player or VMWare WorkStation. Player is a liimited but free version of Workstation.

I tested Kaspersky and MalwareBytes products without problems in VMWare VirtualMachines with various Windows installed.

Comment: VMWare player is only free for non-commercial use. For commercial use, you need VMWare Player Pro.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the clarification.